# Problemas em ler um arquivo em C

Tags: c, imagem, arquivo, txt

Estou tentando abrir e ler um Arquivo em C e depois printar o resultado mas ao printar ele não sai completo no caso ele tem uma imagem em texto de 32 x 32.

Além do mais também gostaria de saber como vou ler um arquivo variável igual ao mesmo (por exemplo estava pensando em armazenar os dados em um vetor e depois varrer com fgets).

```
void abriArquivo(){
    char Linha[1024];
    char *result;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("GIMP.pgm","rt");
    if(file == NULL){
          printf("Problemas na abertura do arquivo \n");
       }
       int i = 1;
       while(!feof(file)){
          result = fgets(Linha,1024,file);
          if(result)
             printf("Linha %d : %s "Linha);
    i++
    }
    fclose(file)
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int contParam;
    char arquivo[100] = "";

    for(contParam = 0; contParam < argc; contParam++){
      if(!strcmp(argv[contParam],"-r")){
         //abrirArquivo();
         contParam += 1;
      }

      else if(!strcmp(argv[contParam],"-arquivo")){
         abrirArquivo();
         contParam += 1;
      }

     /* else if(!strcmp(argv[contParam],"-d")){
         strncpy(,argv[contParam + 1],20);
        */ contParam += 1;
      }
    }
}
```

[Imagem em txt(mesma imagem que a pgm)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zvxov93wtu6lx48/GIMP.txt?dl=0)

[Imagem em pgm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jli66bhd34fey2b/GIMP.pgm?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde,tenta segui essa logica:

```
stdio.h #Dar include em ambas
conio.h

void main()
{
  FILE *arq;
  char Linha[100];
  char *result;
  int i;
  clrscr();

  arq = fopen("GIMP.pgm", "rt");
  if (arq == NULL)  
  {
     printf("Problemas na abertura do arquivo\n");
     return;
  }
  i = 1;
  while (!feof(arq))
  {
      result = fgets(Linha, 100, arq); 
      if (result)  // Se foi possível ler
      printf(arq);
      i++;
  }
  fclose(arq);
}
```

Comment: Boa tarde conseguir mudando o valor de 1024 para 100, obrigado, mas esse printf(arq) não conseguir implementar